# How to add a single executable from a certain directory to PATH environmental variable?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, environment-variables, path

I was looking for a way to add only one specific executable file from a certain directory to the PATH environmental variable. Instead of adding the whole directory `C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta` I would like to add only one file `C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta\firefox.exe`, but I doesn't work that easily.

I found a hint to register the application in the registry under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` as explained here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration#registering-verbs-and-other-file-association-information, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have added the key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe` and set the `(Default)` entry to `C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta\firefox.exe`. Also I have added a `Path` entry and set it to `C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta`. The result looks like this, but as you can see in the CMD window, it doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for? What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Did you open a new command window? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, this is after I restarted the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have added to the registry is a *verb* to a file-type.
This method is used for example to specify the viewer program for `.pdf` files,
or the printer program for such files. This doesn't do what you want.

In addition, it's not possible to add *files* to the PATH, only *folders* can be added.
Adding a file to PATH has no effect, as you have already found out.

I can only see one option here, which is to add the entire folder
`C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta` to the PATH.

If you wish to avoid that, as a workaround you may create a folder
that will contain a `.bat` file named `firefox.bat` that will execute
`firefox.exe`. Include that folder in the PATH, to be able to use `firefox`
as a command. You will avoid this way adding the whole folder
`C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta` to the PATH.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I don't want to bloat the PATH variable with all the other executable in the same folder. I was wondering if maybe there is another way without using the PATH variable that makes it possible to run firefox.exe from the command line?

Comment: You may create a folder that will contain a `.bat` file named `firefox.bat` that will `cd` to that folder and execute `firefox.exe`. Include that folder in the PATH, to be able to use `firefox` as a command. You will avoid this way adding the whole `C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta` to the PATH.

Comment: I have created a one-liner `@"C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta\firefox.exe" %*`, saved it as `C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta\bin\firefox.bat` and added the directory to the PATH variable. It actually seems to work until now. Just wondering if there are any hidden drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that Cmd.exe doesn't use that feature. It a graphical thing for typing in places like Start - Run dialog.

You can force Cmd.exe to use graphical features by using the `start` command.

So `start firefox`.

Better would be

```
 doskey firefox="C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta\firefox.exe" $*
```

You can add this to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
Autorun=doskey firefox="C:\Program Files\Firefox Beta\firefox.exe" $*
```

So it is set each time command prompt is started.

See `doskey /?` and `start /?` for options.

Answer (score -1):

Rightclick This PC -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Comment: This only allows folders, which is specifically not what OP wants.